# antlr grammar for [Foo]-[Bar]-[Baz][X]-[Y][Z]

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3

I am trying to define a grammar that allows for

```
[Foo]-[Bar]-[Baz][X]-[Y][Z]
```

I want to parse this as one set.

I currently have

grammar Sample;

```
items       :   (item association? item?)*;
item        :   LBRACK ID RBRACK;   
association     :   ASSOCIATION;

RBRACK      :   ']';
LBRACK      :   '[';
ASSOCIATION     :   '-';
ID      :   ('a'..'z' |  'A'..'Z' |  '_')*;
```

But this gives an error

```
warning(200): Sample.g:3:30: Decision can match input such as 
"LBRACK ID RBRACK" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

And as a diagram I get
[image]

And I get this railroad diagram

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: The example input you provided, are you parsing that in one chunk? Or do did you post just 2 different examples of possible input?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear that I want to parse it in one chunck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input `[Foo]-[Bar]-[Baz][X]-[Y][Z]`, the following:

```
chunk : items+ EOF;
items : item (ASSOCIATION item)* ;
item  : '[' ID ']' ;

RBRACK      : ']';
LBRACK      : '[';
ASSOCIATION : '-';
ID          : ('a'..'z' |  'A'..'Z' | '_')*;
SPACE       : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'){skip();};
```

produces the following parse tree:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
items : ( '-'? item )* ;
item  : '[' ID ']' ;
ID    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ;
```

which will allow a leading '-' or empty input

or

```
items : item? ( '-'? item )* ;
item  : '[' ID ']' ;
ID    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ;
```

which won't allow a leading '-', but also allows empty input

Comment: Your first suggestion is correct, but the second is not. For example, when there's only one `item` to be parsed, the parser does not know which one too choose from `a=item? ( '-'? b=item )*` (both `$a` and `$b` could be chosen).

Comment: If I use your first suggestion then how would I know which items the association is between. I would like to know in the case of [Foo]-[Bar] that Foo is related to Bar and vice versa. thats why I tried defining two items so that I could refer to them as itemA and itemB when parsing.

Comment: I think you need to refine the problem statement a bit. See my new, improved answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833126/antlr-grammar-for-foo-bar-bazx-yz/4833615#4833615

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
ID        : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')* ;
item      : '[' ID ']' ;
dependency : item ( '-' item )+ ;
list      : ( item | dependency )+
          ;
```